# MATLAB Coder function is undefined in 2014a

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, matlab-coder

I am trying to convert the expm function for calculating the exponential of a matrix from C++ to Mex, in order to increase efficiency. However, this would be a very arduous task to convert the C++ code into Mex viable code, and then run the mex "filename.cpp" function.

Thus I was hoping to use the coder function provided by MATLAB to do this. However I have MATLAB version 2014a and when I try to run the function, it gives me the error:

**Undefined function or variable 'coder'.**

I thought that this function was available in all versions of MATLAB after 2011a, so why is this error occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: On the Mathworks site under [products - Matlab](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab/), it is given under the "Add-On Products" tab. So my guess is that is not included and you'll have to pay for it. Type `ver` to find out which toolboxes you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionality for converting a subset of the MATLAB language to C (N.B., not C++), such as the command `coder`, is included in MATLAB Coder, an add-on product to MATLAB. It's not part of core MATLAB.